# angular nested ng-repeat with server side data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to bind "Thread" and "Comments".

- Thread 1

  - Comment 1
  - Comment 2
  - Comment 3
- Thread 2

  - Comment 1
  - Comment 2
- Thread 3

  - Comment 1
  - Comment 2
  - Comment 3
  - Comment 4
  - Comment 5

I have to fetch "Thread" and "Comment" from database by service. Thread Service gives data of all Threads while "Comment" service takes Thread ID and returns only passed Thread ID Comment.

So, How to bind the data like above nested list by tow separate services.

```js
app.controller('ThreadCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.Threads = [];
    $scope.Comments = [];

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/ThreadList'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Threads = JSON.parse(data);
    });
   
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/CommentList',
        data: JSON.stringify({ ThreadID: 0 }) //The problem is, ThreadID will resolve at runtime
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Threads = JSON.parse(data);
    });
})
```

Comment: If you could please provide a sample JSON(i assume your services return JSON) of what both servicess return i might be able to help you out with your task

Comment: I also noticed that you save the data from both requests to $scope.Threads, i do think the seccond one should be saved to $scope.Comments.

Comment: In my opinion you should handle the desired format from backend as you will be needing nested comments array of objects inside a thread object. Handling it on the frontend is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the comments from server inside the `success` handler of your `threads` call:

```
app.controller('ThreadCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.Threads = [];
    $scope.Comments = [];

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/ThreadList'
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.Threads = JSON.parse(data);

        // iterate over the threads here (this is where they are available already) and fetch the comments by IDs...

        var thread = ...;

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/CommentList',
            data: JSON.stringify({ ThreadID: thread.id })
        }).success(function (data) {
            thread.comments = JSON.parse(data);
        });
    });
})
```